# matlab: find outer edges of objects in a picture

Tags: matlab, edge-detection

I have a picture contains blood smear. What I want to do is to detect the edges of those cells.
[image: blood smear]

I first convert this color image into grayscale image and then fill holes in those cells. And I use the edge() function in matlab to detect edges. Since you can observe the inner part of some cell is much lighter, so there are edges detected inside one cell. The result is shown below:[image: edge detection result]

So is there any methods that only the outer edges of those cells can be detected?

My code is shown below:

```
I = imread('film02_pattern.jpg'); 
t1=graythresh(I);
k1=im2bw(I,t1);
k1=~k1;
se = strel('disk',1);
k1=imfill(k1,'holes');
imshow(k1);
k1=~k1;
bw = edge(k1,'canny',[],sqrt(2));
figure,imshow(bw);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deal with the contours that intersect with the edge of the image, you can use use [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) to separate the background from the unfillable contours. Then, instead of `edge`, you can get the outer perimeters only via [`bwperim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html), but that is just a variation.

```
I = imread('asEW3.jpg');
t1=graythresh(I);
k1=im2bw(I,t1);
k1=~k1;
se = strel('disk',1);
k0=imfill(~k1,'holes');            % new
cc = bwconncomp(k0);               % new
k0(cc.PixelIdxList{1})=0;          % new
k1 = imfill(k1,'holes');
cellMask = k1 | k0;                % new
cellContours = bwperim(cellMask);  % new
cellContours2 = edge(cellMask,'canny',[],sqrt(2)); % new
k1=~k1;
bw = edge(k1,'canny',[],sqrt(2));
figure,imshow(bw); title('original')
figure,imshow(cellContours); title('new, bwperim()')
figure,imshow(cellContours2); title('new, edge()')
```

Using connected components seems a bit like overkill, but there doesn't seem to be an easier way to distinguish background from the centers of cells that hit the edge of the image, at least not while `imfill` is unable to fill those contours.

Comment: Have you tried this code? I tried bwperim(), but the result is the same as before. I think after the image fill is done, the both side of the filled part can be considered as perimeters.

Comment: @user1964417 I didn't try your or my code because posted images never seem to be the same as the originals. I see why imfill didn't work though - it doesn't count the image boundary as an edge.  I'll have a look later.

Comment: I think the imfill() will not fill circle attaching the edge of the image.

Comment: @chappjc is there any function or some part of code that lest you count close contour in canny edge?