# matlab: texture classification

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a histology image like this:

[image: binary histology image]

From the image, we can observe there are two kinds of different cells.

[image: cell type 1] and [image: cell type 2]

Is there any way that I can separate these two types of cells into two groups?

Comment: I would suggest the tag 'image' for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using your [raw image and previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433882/matlab-find-outer-edges-of-objects-in-a-picture) to achieve this?

```
% % % your old code
I=imread(file);
t1=graythresh(I);
k1=im2bw(I,t1);
k1=~k1;
se = strel('disk',1);
k0=imfill(~k1,'holes');           
cc = conncomp(k0);               
k0(cc.PixelIdxList{1})=0;         
k1=imfill(k1,'holes');
mask=k0 | k1;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

This will give you:

[image]

```
I=rgb2hsv(I);  
I=double(I);
I1=I(:,:,1);   % again, the channel that can maximizing the margin between donut and full circle
Imask=(I1-0.2).*(I1-0.9)<0;
k2=mask-Imask;
k2=bwareaopen(k2,100);
```

This will give you:

[image]

```
k2=mask-Imask;
I2=zeros(size(I1,1),size(I1,2),3);
I2(:,:,1)=(k2==1)*255;
I2(:,:,3)=((I1-0.2).*(I1-0.9)<0)*255;
imshow(I2)
```

will finally give you (the two types are stored in two channels in the rgb image):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use `regionprops`

```
props=regionprops(YourBinaryImage, 'Solidity');
```

The objects with a high solidity will be the disks, those with a lower solidity will be the circles.

**(Edit)** More formally:

```
I=imread('yourimage.jpg');
Bw=~im2bw(I, 0.5);
BWnobord = imclearborder(Bw, 4); % clears the partial objects
Props=regionprops(BWnobord, 'All');
solidity=cell2mat({Props.Solidity});
Images={Props.Image};
```

Access the elements of `Images` where the value in `solidity` is higher than 0.9 and you get your disks. The circles are the other ones.

Hope it helps